# Swift: Difference between NSFetchRequest and NSFetchResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a hard time to understand the difference between the NSFetchRequest and the NSFetchResultsController. 
I also don't know in which situation I would choose which one of them.

I would be really happy, if someone could explain it in simple terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest` is a simple static description of the set of `NSManagedObjects` you would like to grab from your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

`NSFetchResultsController` helps manage the objects fetched for use in an (`NS`/`UI`) `TableView`/`CollectionView`. The set of objects returned by an `NSFetchRequest` can change as objects are edited/inserted/deleted in your NSManagedObjectContext. `NSFetchResultsController` will help you track these changes.

`NSFetchResultsController` is configured with an `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: ...also worth mentioning UICollectionView